# Links and Back within PDF

Tags: adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I have a PDF document that has links in various places to figures/tables that are towards the end of the document. Let's say I have a link on page 2 that you click to go to Figure 7. I have the same link on page 4 when I reference the same figure. How can I create a link that takes me back to page 2 or back to page 4 (whichever was the previous location) at Figure 7 so the reader doesn't need to constantly scroll the whole way back to where they were?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Adobe JavaScript to do this. Create a button which runs `app.goBack();` on click. This will only work in PDF viewers supporting JavaScript (Adobe Reader does, most others don't).

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat Reader has a "Go back to the previous view" function that can be used by the reader to go back to his previous page, without any extra action on your part.

Otherwise, I cannot see any other solution than inserting links in Figure 7 to go to pages 2 and 4, which is not a very easy solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that is what we have advised our users to do. We also started including the figures as separate PDF's so we can just have a hyperlink that opens the Figure PDF and they can have both open at once. It worked well!